# Loop Until In Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hi I am trying to loop until it finds the last cell and then stops but when it reaches the empty cell it is giving me an error because there is noone to email to in the last empty cell. I will copy in my code so you might understand what I mean.

```
Sub SendMassEmail()
  row_number = 0

  Do
    DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    item_in_review = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)
    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim full_name As String
    Dim exam_grade As String

    mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("G3")
    full_name = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number) & " " & Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
    exam_grade = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "exam_grade_replace", exam_grade)

    Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), "Final Year Exam Results", mail_body_message)

  Loop Until item_in_review = ""

  MsgBox "The Email Sending Process Is Complete!"
End Sub
```

**EDIT**...The SendEmail sub.

```
Sub SendEmail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
  Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

  olMail.To = what_address
  olMail.Subject = subject_line
  olMail.Body = mail_body
  olMail.Send
End Sub
```

Basically what is happening is it sends all the emails in the list but when it hits the last cell that is empty it throws a run time error and I believe this is because there is no email address in the last empty cell to send to. So does anyone know how I can make it stop when it reaches the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub SendMassEmail()

row_number = 1
item_in_review = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)



Do Until item_in_review = ""

DoEvents

    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim full_name As String
    Dim exam_grade As String

    mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("G3")
    full_name = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number) & " " & Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
    exam_grade = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "exam_grade_replace", exam_grade)

    Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), "Final Year Exam Results", mail_body_message)
     row_number = row_number + 1
     item_in_review = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number) ' This is the new line
Loop
MsgBox "The Email Sending Process Is Complete!"


End Sub
```

I have changed the "Loop Until" to "Do Until" - your procedure was trying to run the full code between the "Do" and "Loop Until", when really you wanted it to stop as soon as your criteria (item_in_review = "") was met - you achieve this by testing the position BEFORE the loop is entered.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of why this works to your answer?

Comment: I hope I've given a good enough explaination below the code. Feel free to edit further.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't want to go editing your answer without giving you a chance first. Thank you. I think that gives OP a better chance of understanding where he went wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jiminy Cricket I see where your coming through, Im still getting a run time error though saying that "There must be at least one name or distribution list in the To, Cc, or Bcc box.

Any ideas how to stop this runtime error?

Comment: I have done it now, added the code to the bottom of the original post that is

Comment: I've edited my post and showed where I've changed it. The 'item_in_review' wasn't updating before the loop, so it wasn't stopping when it should have.

Comment: Jiminy Cricket your an absolute hero! If I could I would buy you a beer right now!

Comment: It took a few edits, but we got there. Can you mark the question as answered by clicking the 'tick' by the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the last cell in a continuous range is Range.End(xlDown). Range.End(xlDown).row will you give that cell's row index.

```
Sub SendMassEmail()

  For each row in Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row)

    item_in_review = Sheet1.Range("A" & row.row)
    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim full_name As String
    Dim exam_grade As String

    mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("G3")
    full_name = Sheet1.Range("B" & row.row) & " " & Sheet1.Range("C" & row.row)
    exam_grade = Sheet1.Range("D" & row.row)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
    mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "exam_grade_replace", exam_grade)

    Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row.row), "Final Year Exam Results",     mail_body_message)

  Next row

  MsgBox "The Email Sending Process Is Complete!"
End Sub
```